# Sending Large amouts of data from Unmannaged C++ application to Managed C#

Tags: c#, c++, communication

we have two applications, a native C++ application and a managed C#/WPF UI that creates input for, executes & reads output generated by the native application. Currently, communication between the two is done with XML & plain txt files.

However, the amount of output data is quite large & we are looking for a better approach to this. A solution that uses something like Memorystream would be ideal because it would easy to switch the output generation from a filestream to a memorystream.

However, how does one bridge the gap between managed & unmanaged? What is the most efficient way to do this?

Note: Many of the questions related to this are about a function call from a managed to an unmaged dll. These are two separate applications running independently. The UI spawns the native application, this is the only link between the two.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try a named pipe
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/interprocess-communication-using-named-pipes-in-csharp

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the way you produce/consume data

- named pipes or socket -  constant stream of data
- shared memory -  continuous updated data

Comment: -1. Named pipes internally DO use shared memory on the same computer.

Comment: i know. so what ? this doesn't means you should never use shared memory. if the poster updates only small parts of a big data it's a god idea to use shared memory & synchronization instead of pipes/sockets

Comment: I agree with @cprogrammer. It's like saying that SQL uses I/O access and therefore shouldn't be used. It's an added abstraction that could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use standard input/output?  Your C++ program can write to stdout using normal "printf" or "cout" commands.

Your .NET app can then capture this data using http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx, for example.  Same goes for standard input: use stdin to send commands to the C++ program.

Using named pipes is nice and might be the answer if you need more than two streams.  But it would probably be more work on the C++ end of things.

Comment: We already use this for sending status updates from the native app to the UI, but is this really an efficient way to send large amounts of data (50 MB+)?

Comment: Give it a try... it's easy enough to test the concept.  Or, just go with named pipes.  I wouldn't be surprised if stdout is fast enough though.  I guess the question is: how fast do you need it to be?